# Angular: button with loading state

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I am pretty new to Angular (6), and I am trying to build a button with a loading state.

Basically I want to right in the html:
 `<my-special-button (click)="doSomething()"></my-special-button>`
And that MySpecialButton component subscribe on its own to the observable returned by doSomething() in a generic way so that it can update its status (without having to add a boolean in the parent component to update the status)

In AngularJS I would simply use the "@" binding, but I can't find a proper solution in Angular 6.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Are you looking for `(click)="doSomething()"`?

Comment: and for parent/child status you could use `@Input` to get state from parent component and `@Output` to emit something to parent component?

Comment: I would really like not to have to set anything special in the parent components. I would love it so clean and generic that I can use it as a normal button.